# performance impact of logging input requests using axis handler

Tags: java, performance, web-services, axis

I am planning to log the xml requests to my web service using apache axis handler. Will this slow the web service down?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong question. Adding logging has of course it's computational cost as extra code is executed, I/O operations are performed etc. But log4j is optimized for that.

The question you should ask is what performance impact does logging have? If your web service is called once in a while and providing a response takes 1 minute, does a few miliseconds spent in logging matter? If instead you have a web service for a low latency application where request load is high and response time must be very low can you afford a few extra miliseconds?

What I'm trying to say is that you normally add logging, configure it to log only what you are interested in, then profile and test to see if it has any noticeable performance impact and if that is acceptable given your application's needs.